# Django view execution order for same url pattern requests?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Let we say two users access the same urls that lead two requests were send to django views. The question is, how does django deal with these two requests? Does them be handled in two different threads simultaneously or when one end it request-middleware-response life cycle then the other be handled?

Comment: You may need to take a look at some Python WSGI like [`gunicorn`](http://gunicorn.org/) and [`uwsgi`](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't do anything at all. It is entirely up to the server, which has already determined (according to its configuration) whether to run Django in multiple processes and/or threads, and so distributes incoming requests among those.